# Slow performance in List View

Tags: android, image, listview, android-asynctask, adapter

I'm having a really weird problem with my Android app. Simply put, the problem occurs when I put image content into a `ListView item`.
For instance; let's say I have a `Fragment` with the following layout;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the following layout for my 'list items';

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_image_height"
        android:id="@+id/listimage"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listtitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listimage"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listsubtitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listtitle"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listtitle"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listtitle"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listimage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listtitle"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/listtitle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This all goes well. The list presents itself just like the way I want it to. But, whenever I'm starting to put images (content) into the `ImageView`, things get messy. Whatever I do, the list loads horrendously slow and scrolling is near to impossible.
I've tried multiple ways of loading images and putting them into the `ImageView`.
Things I've tried:

- Using a `ViewHolder` in a custom `Adapter`, loading the Images in an `AsyncTask` from the `Drawables` folder and putting them into the `ImageView` on the `.onPostExecute()`
- Using a `ViewHolder` in a custom `Adapter`, loading the images from the `Drawables` without using an `AsyncTask`.
- Using [EasyAdapter](https://github.com/ribot/easy-adapter), by loading the images from the `Drawables` on the `onSetValues()`.
- Using [EasyAdapter](https://github.com/ribot/easy-adapter), by loading the images from the `Assets` folder on `onSetValues()

All of this didn't really do anything different but for the last option. The last option made the list more acceptable but still loading is really slow. (I press the button, the `fragment` gets initiated and I try to open it using the `TransactionManager`, this only seems to freeze the app for about 2-5 seconds before showing the list.) Scrolling is more acceptable as well, but still not as good as it could and *should* be.

If I comment out the part where I **set** the Image into the `ImageView` and run it again there is absolutely nothing amiss with the view.
What it all boils down to, is that setting the content from the Drawables folder is a no go. (although I've done this for every app I've built without problems). Setting the image content from the Assets folder improves performance immensely, but still not near the performance I'm expecting. Even when using the EasyAdapter as follows is giving a horrible UX:

```
@LayoutId(R.layout.list_default)
public class ListAdapter extends ItemViewHolder<Item> {

    @ViewId(R.id.listimage)
    ImageView image;

    @ViewId(R.id.listtitle)
    TextView title;

    @ViewId(R.id.listsubtitle)
    TextView subtitle;

    public BeetListAdapter(View view) {
        super(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSetValues(BeetItem item, PositionInfo positionInfo) {
        title.setText(item.getTitle());
        subtitle.setText(item.getLatinname());
        image.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset(item.getFirstImageName()));

        getView().setTag(R.id.itemid, item.getId());
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open("images/" + strName + ".jpg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        return bitmap;
    }

}
```

Do you guys have ANY idea why this is? I'm not finding ANY reason nor a solution to why this is.
Thanks in advance!

**tl;dr**: *My `ListView` is really slow when I put images into an `ImageView`. It doesn't seem to matter how and where they come from (ram, disk, internet). Whenever I do `imageView.setImageBitmap()` or `imageView.setDrawable()`, performance plummets and scrolling is nearly impossible.*

Comment: Did you tried to scale the images for the size that you need? Also, I recommend you to load the images into another thread (could be a asynctask) and also cache the images.

Comment: what is the size and dimension of the image you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair, none of the above really fixed my problem and I decided to implement a [library 
that helps with these kinds of problems.](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

For the reference, this is the configuration I initialised *Android Universal Image Loader* with;

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
        .threadPoolSize(5)
        .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
        .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
        .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 320, null)
        .build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Without implementing the `AsyncTask`, I now have a really good UX in the app.

Answer (score 3):

**Cache the image if possible, scale it down**. [Aquery library](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/) may help you with all these task.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The Library you provided wasn't what I was looking for. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader was.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are loading image from assets in Main(UI) thread that's why it looks choppy. So load image in asynktask like this.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ItemViewHolder<ClipData.Item> {

    @ViewId(R.id.listimage)
    ImageView image;

    @ViewId(R.id.listtitle)
    TextView title;

    @ViewId(R.id.listsubtitle)
    TextView subtitle;

    public BeetListAdapter(View view) {
        super(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSetValues(BeetItem item, PositionInfo positionInfo) {
        title.setText(item.getTitle());
        subtitle.setText(item.getLatinname());
        getBitmapFromAsset(item.getFirstImageName(), image);
        getView().setTag(R.id.itemid, item.getId());
    }



    private void getBitmapFromAsset(final String strName,final ImageView imageView)
    {
        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>(){

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try{
                    AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
                    InputStream istr = null;
                    try {
                        istr = assetManager.open("images/" + strName + ".jpg");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
                    return bitmap;
                }catch (Throwable e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if(result!=null){
                    image.setImageBitmap(result);
                }
            }
        }.execute();

    }

}
```

Comment: It seems like this is not entirely what I want. The images get loaded pretty fast and the performance is way better. But, the Adapter randomly sets the Image on the first List Item, when it's done randomly placing the images it goes on to the next, until all image views are correctly set. This is not really the behaviour i was anticipating.

Answer (score 0):

Do not hardcode `LruMemoryCache`. because on some devices you will recieve:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)
```

Here is options for fasters load of images, and scrolling listview:

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .build();
        int memClass;
        memClass = ( (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE ) )
                .getMemoryClass();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .threadPoolSize(1)//from 1-5
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
//                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) /or this
                .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(memClass * 1024 * 1024/8))
                .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 320, null)
                .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance() .init(config);
```